# $x|\mu \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $\mu|x_0 \sim N(x_0, \sigma^2)$ what is $x|x_0$

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, bayesian

I am trying to calculate the distribution of some univariate variable $X$ that follows a Normal distribution with mean $\mu$ but $\mu$ itself is also random. For simplicity I assume Normal distributions with the same known variance. Hence:

$$ p(x | \mu) = \frac{1}{\sqrt {2 \pi \sigma^2}} \exp-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}$$

and

$$ p(\mu | x_o) = \frac{1}{\sqrt {2 \pi \sigma^2}} \exp-\frac{(\mu - x_0)^2}{2 \sigma^2}$$

Therefore:

\begin{align}
      p(x) & = \int p(x|\mu) \, \,p(\mu|x_0) \, d\mu \\\\
      & = \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2} \int \exp\big[-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\big( (x-\mu)^2 + (\mu-x_0)^2 \big)\big]d\mu
\end{align}

Expanding now the demoninator inside the exponential function we get
\begin{align}
(x-\mu)^2 + (\mu-x_0)^2 & = x^2 + \mu^2 - 2 x \mu + \mu^2 + x_0^2 - 2 x_0 \mu \\\\
& = 2\mu^2 -2\mu(x + x_0) +x^2+x_0^2 \\\\
& = 2\mu^2 -2\mu(x + x_0) +x^2+x_0^2 + 2\, x\,x_0 - 2\, x\,x_0 \\\\
& = 2\mu^2 -2\mu(x + x_0) +(x+x_0)^2 - 2\, x\,x_0 \\\\
& = \mu + (\mu-(x+x_0))^2 -  2\, x\,x_0
\end{align}

Can I work this any further please and get the distribution of $x$ (given $x_0$) or am I stuck? Is there another more (mathematically) convenient distribution for $\mu|x_0$ that is typically used in these cases?

Comment: It is a bit of algebra, but you should be able to show that this reduces and can show that $ x | x_0 \sim N(x_0, 2\sigma^2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler way to look at this, without needing to use the density, is to recognise that $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)+\mu$. From that, you can say

\begin{align}
x\vert x_0 &\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)+\mu\vert x_0\\
&\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)+\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)+x_0\\
&\sim\mathcal{N}(0,2\sigma^2)+x_0\\
&\sim\mathcal{N}(x_0,2\sigma^2)
\end{align}

Comment: Though it is maybe clear from OP, we probably should note that the two normal distributions you are adding are independent.

Comment: Quite neat, thnx!